# Java - Adding/appending time start time(00:00:00.000) & end time (23.59.59.999) to date

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime, datetime-format

I'm getting start date as "2016-06-01" and end date as "2016-07-01" (in string format) for searching records in `MongoDB`. Need pointer/guidance to append start time (00:00:00.000) to start date and maximum time(23.59.59.999) to end date as below in Java using `java.util.Date` or any others which supported by `MongoDB`.

```
Example : 
Start Date+with time : 2016-06-01T00:00:00.000
End Date+with time : 2016-07-01T23:59:59.999
```

Answer (score 0):

public class DateSample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String startDate = "2016-06-01";
    String endDate = "2016-07-01";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date strDate = formatter.parse(startDate+" 00:00:00.000");
    Date enDate = formatter.parse(endDate+" 23:59:59.999");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(strDate));
    System.out.println(formatter.format(enDate));

}
```

}

You will get
2016-06-01 00:00:00
2016-07-01 23:59:59

Comment: Getting both start & end date as same - Start: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1970 and 
End:Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1970

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` for this. Here is an example that might shed some light on what you are trying to do:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
String startTime = "T00:00:00.000";
String endTime = "T23:59:59.999";
//here I used the LocalDateTime parser to parse the data+startTime/endTime
LocalDateTime startLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-07-01"+startTime);
LocalDateTime endLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-07-01"+endTime );
//with the LocalDateTime, you can then to whatever you want
//as an example, I am parsing it using ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME :
String strinStartTime= dtf.format(LocalDateTime.parse("2016-07-22"+startTime));
```

I hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

If you are running under jdk 1.8, use LocalDateTime

LocalDateTime is an embedded api of jdk 1.8. You can found explaination here docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html. You can use minus* or plus*, and parse methods

Comment: Not a good Answer for Stack Overflow. Both Questions and Answers should be *specific*, laser-focused on a solution. Vaguely pointing to a library is generally not enough.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for this bad answer. LocalDateTime is an embedded api of jre 1.8. You can found explaination here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html. You can use minus* or plus*,  and parse methods.

Comment: You should put that content in your Question via the "edit" link or button. Otherwise you can delete your answer to avoid down-votes. Do post again when you have time for a full fleshed-out Answer.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of( "2016-06-01" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt start = startDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt stop = startDate.plusMonths(1).atStartOfDay( zoneId ) ;
// Perform database search where ( ( x >= start ) AND ( x < stop ) ) . Notice '>=' versus '<' with no 'equals' on the latter.
```

If you need strings…

```
String outputStart = start.toInstant().toString() ;  // 2016-05-31T22:00:00Z  Paris in the summer is two hours ahead of UTC.
String outputStop = stop.toInstant().toString() ;  // 2016-06-30T22:00:00Z
```

## Details

The [Answer by ishmaelMakitla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529493/642706) is good in that it points to using the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. But it focuses on strings rather than objects. Also it does not discuss the crucial issue of time zone.

The java.time classes include:

- `LocalDate` for a date-only value with no time-of-day and no time zone.
- [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) for a time-of-day value without a date and without a time zone.

  LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-06-01" );  // Parsing ISO 8601 standard date format.
  LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.MIN;  // '00:00'.

Both of those classes can be used in factory methods to instantiate [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) and other classes.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( startDate , startTime );
```

In code above we used [`LocalTime.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN) to get `00:00`. To directly answer your Question, you can also use [`LocalTime.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX) in the same way to get `23:59:59.999999999`. But I do *not* recommend doing so. Read below about "Half-Open".

## Time zone

Time zone is crucial in determining a date and a time. For any given moment the date and the hour-of-day both vary by time zone. A few minutes after midnight in Paris is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal.

The `Local…` types are *not* actual moments on the timeline. They represent a vague idea about *possible* moments. As noted above, the first moment of June 1st in Paris is simultaneously May 31st at 6 PM in Montréal. So before performing your database search you need to assign a time zone to your `LocalDateTime`. Applying a `ZoneId` produces a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Perhaps your date-time was intended to be Paris.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId );
```

Or perhaps you intended [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). This all depends on your business rules, the context in which your app operates. For UTC, we use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) as UTC is not a full time zone but rather a mere [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

To get a string as asked for in the Question, extract LocalDate and call `toString()`. But I do not recommend this as it ignores time zone (read on down below).

```
String output = odt.toLocalDateTime.toString();  // Not likely to be what you really need.
```

Best practice in databases is to store the date-time in UTC. I don't know about MongoDB. Be sure to read the doc on how your database driver in Java may be affecting/translating the values you specify.

## Start of Day

Be aware that a day does not always start at `00:00:00`. In some time zones DST or other anomalies means the day may start at some other time such as `01:00`.

The java.time classes will make adjustments as needed in some situations. Be sure to read the class doc so you see if the behavior matches your expectations & needs.

You can ask java.time to find the starting time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDate.of( "2016-06-01" ).atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

## Half-Open

Your attempt to determine the end of the day is a problem. That last second is infinitely divisible. Traditional Unix-oriented libraries resolve to whole seconds, the old date-time classes in Java resolve to milliseconds, some databases like Postgres may resolve to microseconds, and java.time and other databases such as H2 resolve to nanoseconds. Do not get in the middle of that.

Generally in date-time programming of a span of time, the best practice is "Half-Open". The beginning of the span is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So searching for a month of data in Paris zone means searching for records where the *date-time is equal to or later* than the start and *less than (but not including)* the stop.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of( "2016-06-01" );
ZonedDateTime zdt start = startDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
ZonedDateTime zdt stop = startDate.plusMonths(1).atStartOfDay( zoneId );
// Perform database search where ( ( x >= start ) AND ( x < stop ) ) . Notice '>=' versus '<' with no 'equals' on the latter.
```

Similarly, the month of records for UTC rather than Paris.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.UTC;
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of( "2016-06-01" );
OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.of( startDate , zoneOffset );
OffsetDateTime stop = OffsetDateTime.plusMonths(1).of( startDate , zoneOffset );
// Perform database search where ( ( x >= start ) AND ( x < stop ) ) . Notice '>=' versus '<' with no 'equals' on the latter.
```

Using the Half-Open approach consistently throughout your app where handling spans of time will make your code more sensible and easier to understand. You can also train your users to think this way. We all use Half-Open intuitively in situations situations like "Lunch break is from 12:00 to 13:00". We all know this means be back from lunch *before* the clock strikes `13:00:00.0`.